# Any way to check for html attribute mispelling in HTMLHint?

Tags: html

Using the vscode extension HTMLHint, is there any way to configure it to check for attribute mispelling? Example: I put reqiured instead of required. Can it check against all accepted attributes and then tell me if my attribute doesn't match any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `VSCode IntelliSense` **(Ctrl+Space)** will give you a list of all related Attributes, this will reduce spelling mistakes in keywords. Toggle it ON if it is turned off.